# Grouping when working with parameters and OleDbCommand, Crystal reports

Tags: c#, group-by, crystal-reports, report, oledbcommand

I have an sql statement with group by and parameters:

```
string comstring = 
    "SELECT NOVI.GBR as gbrnov, 
            NOVI.AB as abnov, 
            NALOG1.DATA as datanov, 
            Min(NALOG1.POCKM) AS MinOfPOCKM, 
            Max(NALOG1.KRAJKM) AS MaxOfKRAJKM, 
            (Max(NALOG1.KRAJKM)-Min(NALOG1.POCKM)) AS RAZLIKA, 
            Count(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0991000'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)) AS Gorivo, 
            Avg(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0991000'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)/100) AS potrosgor100km, 
            Sum(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0993050' Or [MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0993051'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)) AS Motmaslo, 
            Sum(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0992201'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)) AS Addblue, 
            ([Addblue]/[Gorivo])*100 AS Addbluegor, 
            Sum(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0999001'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)) AS Antifriz, 
            NOVI.DATAP, 
            NOVI.DATAS, 
            IIf(([NOVI].[KM]<=([NOVI].[KMS1]+[NOVI].[KMS2])),'ZA SERVIS',(IIf(([NOVI].[KM]<=([NOVI].[KMP1]+[NOVI].[KMP2])),'PROVERKA',''))) AS Zabeleska 
     FROM (NALOG1 INNER JOIN NOVI ON NALOG1.GBRV = NOVI.GBR) 
     INNER JOIN MAGACIN ON NOVI.GBR = MAGACIN.GBR 
         where (((NOVI.GBR)>=? And (NOVI.GBR)<=?) 
             AND ( ((NOVI.AB)=?) 
             OR ((NOVI.AB)=?) ) 
             AND ((NALOG1.DATA)<=? and (NALOG1.DATA)>=?) ) 
     GROUP BY NOVI.GBR, 
              NOVI.AB, 
              NALOG1.DATA, 
              ([Addblue]/[Gorivo])*100, 
              NOVI.DATAP, 
              NOVI.DATAS, 
              IIf(([NOVI].[KM]<=([NOVI].[KMS1]+[NOVI].[KMS2])),'ZA SERVIS',(IIf(([NOVI].[KM]<=([NOVI].[KMP1]+[NOVI].[KMP2])),'PROVERKA','')))";
```

I get an error `No value given for one or more required parameters` in

```
oleDBDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet2,"Tabela");
```

When using it with certain values like:

```
string comstring = 
    "SELECT NOVI.GBR as gbrnov, 
            NOVI.AB as abnov, 
            NALOG1.DATA as datanov, 
            Min(NALOG1.POCKM) AS MinOfPOCKM, 
            Max(NALOG1.KRAJKM) AS MaxOfKRAJKM, 
            (Max(NALOG1.KRAJKM)-Min(NALOG1.POCKM)) AS RAZLIKA, 
            Count(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0991000'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)) AS Gorivo, 
            Avg(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0991000'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)/100) AS potrosgor100km, 
            Sum(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0993050' Or [MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0993051'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)) AS Motmaslo, 
            Sum(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0992201'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)) AS Addblue, 
            ([Addblue]/[Gorivo])*100 AS Addbluegor, 
            Sum(IIf(([MAGACIN.SIFRA]='0999001'),[MAGACIN.KOL],Null)) AS Antifriz, 
            NOVI.DATAP, 
            NOVI.DATAS, 
            IIf(([NOVI].[KM]<=([NOVI].[KMS1]+[NOVI].[KMS2])),'ZA SERVIS',(IIf(([NOVI].[KM]<=([NOVI].[KMP1]+[NOVI].[KMP2])),'PROVERKA',''))) AS Zabeleska 
     FROM (NALOG1 INNER JOIN NOVI ON NALOG1.GBRV = NOVI.GBR) 
     INNER JOIN MAGACIN ON NOVI.GBR = MAGACIN.GBR 
         where (((NOVI.GBR)>='1001' And (NOVI.GBR)<='1080') 
         AND ( ((NOVI.AB)='AK') 
         OR ((NOVI.AB)='AK') ) 
         AND ((NALOG1.DATA)<=#10/31/2011# 
         and (NALOG1.DATA)>=#10/31/2011#) ) 
     GROUP BY NOVI.GBR, 
              NOVI.AB, 
              NALOG1.DATA, 
              ([Addblue]/[Gorivo])*100, 
              NOVI.DATAP, 
              NOVI.DATAS, 
              IIf(([NOVI].[KM]<=([NOVI].[KMS1]+[NOVI].[KMS2])),'ZA SERVIS',(IIf(([NOVI].[KM]<=([NOVI].[KMP1]+[NOVI].[KMP2])),'PROVERKA','')))";
```

there wasn't any problem.

Could anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem with your query:

```
where (((NOVI.GBR)>=? And (NOVI.GBR)<=?) 
             AND ( ((NOVI.AB)=?) 
             OR ((NOVI.AB)=?) ) 
             AND ((NALOG1.DATA)<=? and (NALOG1.DATA)>=?) )
```

You need to supply proper value instead of `?`, probably you might do `'?'`, but I think it won't work for `(NALOG1.DATA)`(By seeing your other query I'm guessing that, its data type is `Date`)

**Edit for Comments:**

If you are using parameters, then you need to pass them on the order on which `?` is used. You cannot use named parameters like below, in `oledbcommand`

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", "1001");
```

If you used 6 `?` in your query then, you need to pass 6 arguments according to the order.

```
        OleDbParameter[] oledbParams = new OleDbParameter[6];

        //To be added in proper order.
        oledbParams[0] = new OleDbParameter("PN1", "1001");
        oledbParams[1] = new OleDbParameter("PN2", "1002");
        .
        .
        oledbParams[6] = new OleDbParameter("DateValue", DateTime.Now.Date);

        foreach (var p in oledbParams)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(p);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is in that part. When I put proper value, as shown above, it works fine. But when I want to use the values that the user chose, using the form before pressing the button, there was an error. So, when using ? for parameters. I tried '?' as well, but nothing changed. Here is how I fill the ?: if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gbr1", "1001");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gbr2", "1080");
                button1.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }......

Comment: when you are using `Parameters` you have to assign them to the proper field instead of `?`

Comment: Yes, I know that, and I use them in the appropriate order, And I use 6 parameters. And when I used it as you reccomend me command.Parameters.Add("1001");   I got this error: The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.